# Bit cost of bit shift

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory, bit-manipulation, big-o

I updated a question I asked before with this but as the original question was answered I'm guessing I should ask it seperately in a new question.

Take for example the simple multiplication algorithm. I see in numerous places the claim that this is a Log^2(N) operation. The given explanation is that this is due to it consisting of Log(N) additions of a Log(N) number.

The problem I have with this is although that is true it ignores the fact that each of those Log(N) numbers will be the result of a bit shift and by the end we will have bitshifted at least Log(N) times. As bitshift by 1 is a Log(N) operation the bitshifts considered alone give us Log^2(N) operations.

It therefore makes no sense to me when I see it further claimed that in practice multiplication doesn't in fact use Log^2(N) operations as various methods can reduce the number of required additions. Since the bitshifting alone gives us Log^2(N) I'm left confused as to how that claim can be true.

In fact any shift and add method would seem to have this bit cost irrespective of how many addition's there are.

Even if we use perfect minimal bit coding any Mbit by Nbit multiplication will result in an approx M+Nbit Number so M+N bits will have to have been shifted at least N times just to output/store/combine terms, meaning a minimum N^2 bit operations.

This seems to contradict the claimed number of operations for Toom-Cook etc so can someone please point out where my reasoning is flawed.

Comment: In the context of algorithms like Toom-Cook, that "shift" isn't really a shift. It's just adding to a different memory address. So that "shift" is free.

Comment: Thanks. Just to double check. Are you saying that the shift in Cook-Tombs is free but the shifts in the shift and add methods are not?

Comment: It's probably worth noting that, if we're talking about a native word size, bit shift is probably O(1) (maybe not really, but by the time you deal with the full pipeline and instruction retirement, etc., it might as well be). If we're talking about a multi-word extended precesion integer library (or simulating hardware bit shifts in software), though, bit shift is likely O(N) on the size of the integer.

Comment: That was my previous question but the answer was that it is not O(1) but O(N) for a N bit word even of native size. After all your not just shifting one bit your moving all N bits by 1. By your logic multi word would then be O(A) where A is the number of words? I've developed some new algorithms for various mathematical operations and as they use shift and few adds it's important for me to have this tied down. I wasn't sure if I could perfom the shifts without the O(N) cost but the answer I accepted seems to indicate I can by instead specifying the starting bit.

Comment: @RhuaidhriTynan shifts done in hardware are not restricted to shifting one bit at a time - proper use of various circuit components allow all N bits to be moved to their new location in one step in parallel, making it O(1). Doing it in software is different, which is why the multi-word algorithm must be O(N) (or O(A), as you mentioned) - you have to handle each word in turn. The accepted answer is more about being able to combine two O(N) operations into a single operation that is still O(N), as opposed to less efficient algorithms that might not perform as well...

Comment: I get what the accepted answer is about that was just me putting it badly. Now that I think about it I get why the multiword would cost more since you can't just shift all words by 1 you also have to worry about whether a bit needs to carry from one word to the next. Is it acceptable practise for me to specify the bit cost of the shifts being O(1) aslong as I restrict to native word size?

Comment: I think that's probably a safe assumption on most desktop/laptop/server systems these days. Some embedded platforms may not expend the hardware budget to make shifts O(1), but that's not exactly my area of expertise...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the way around this issue is the fact that you can do the operation

```
 a + b << k
```

without having to perform any shifts at all.  If you imagine what the addition would look like, it would look something like this:

```
  bn b(n - 1) ... b(n-k) b(n-k-1)     b0   0    ... 0  0  0  0
                  an     a(n-1)   ... ak a(k-1) ... a3 a2 a1 a0
```

In other words, the last k digits of the number will just be the last k digits of the number a, the middle digits will consist of the sum of a subset of b's digits and a subset of a's digits, and the leading digits can be formed by doing a ripple propagation of any carries up through the remaining digits of b.  In other words, the total runtime will be proportional to the number of digits in a and b, plus the number of places to do the shift.

The real trick here is realizing that you can shift by k places without doing k individual shifts by one place over.  Rather than shuffling everything down k times, you can just figure out where the bits are going to end up and write them there directly.  In other words, the cost of a shift by k bits is not k times the cost of a shift by 1 bit.  It's O(N + k), where N is the number of bits in the number.

Consequently, if you can implement multiplication in terms of some number of "add two numbers with a shift" operations, you will not necessarily have to do O((log n)<sup>2</sup>) bit operations.  Each addition does O(log n + k) total bit operations, so if k is small (say, O(log n)) and you only do a small number of additions, then you can do better than O((log n)<sup>2</sup>) bit operations.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful but I'm going to let it sink in for a few minutes before I accept. Unfortunately I can't vote up as I don't have the rep for it.